# how to open a UDP socket with two different ports?

Tags: c, sockets

i opened a UDP socket on IP 192.168.210.120 and port 5000.
and i want to recieve data on two different port (5000,6000).

please guide

Comment: Please give more information on what you have  tried so far and what the results have been. Also more information on your desired goal or actual problem would be helpful if you want an answer.

Comment: So open a second socket. You can't bind one socket to two ports.

Comment: @SilverSkin The question is perfectly clear as is.

Comment: Ok, but then I'll refer to this old question instead :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687323/udp-receiving-data-on-multiple-ports

Comment: @EJP SilverSkin has a point. Voting to close this question as duplicate of the mentioned one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not possible with a single socket.

By definition, UDP sockets can only bind to a single port. That's how these sockets work.

You can, however, open two sockets. And then, maybe using two accepting threads, maybe using other mechanisms (POSIX `select`) detect connections to these.

How you can juggle multiple listening UDP sockets depends on your programming language/socket abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

As was previously mentioned, if you want to receive data on two different ports, you need a separate socket for each one.  You can however use the `select()` function to to monitor both sockets at once.

```
int socket1, socket2;
fd_set rfds;
struct timeval tv;
int retval;

/* bind socket1 to 5000 and socket2 to 6000, ommitted for brevity */

FD_ZERO(&rfds);
FD_SET(socket1, &rfds);
FD_SET(socket2, &rfds);

/* Wait up to five seconds. */
tv.tv_sec = 5;
tv.tv_usec = 0;

retval = select(FD_SETSIZE, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

if (retval == -1) {
    perror("select()");
} else if (retval == 0) {
    printf("No data within five seconds.\n");
} else {
    printf("Data is available now.\n");
    if (FD_ISSET(socket1, &rfds)) {
        /* call recvfrom on socket1 to read data */
    }
    if (FD_ISSET(socket2, &rfds)) {
        /* call recvfrom on socket2 to read data */
    }
}
```

Comment: The first parameter of `select()` is wrong. You are setting it to the number of sockets in the `fd_set`, but it needs to be set to the highest socket value +1 instead, eg: `int maxfd = max(socket1, socket2); retval = select(maxfd+1, ...);`

Comment: I would also suggest changing `if (retval)` to `if (retval > 0)`, or else move the `(retval == 0)` code up into the second `if` block and the `(retval > 0)` code into the final `else` block, if only for better readability.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks, I also forgot about FD_SETSIZE.  I'll add that edit.

Comment: Not all platforms allow `FD_SETSIZE` to be passed.  Best to just use a real max value from the sockets, that will work on all platforms (except Windows, but that parameter is ignored so it does not matter in that case).